# Operation cancellation

Tags: c#, asynchronous

*Brevity is for kings as it requires context and context is for kings. Me.*

[GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/drycancellation) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dry.Cancellations)

How many times you have been writing something like this passing those tedious logger/token parameters?

```
interface IMyService
{
    void Method1(…, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token);
    void Method2(…, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token);
    …
}
```

Enough is enough. Please see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229222/operation-logger) about ambient logging. Below is about ambient cancellation.

What we are about to do is to use a special `Cancellation` helper class like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new Cancellation())
        {
            Task.Run(PingAsync);
            ReadLine();
            Cancellation.Request();
            ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static async Task PingAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!Cancellation.Requested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, Cancellation.Token);
                WriteLine("Ping");
            }

            Cancellation.ThrowIfRequested();
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            WriteLine("Ping cancelled");
        }
    }
```

Where `Cancellation` is defined as:

```
public class Cancellation : IDisposable
{
    static AsyncLocal<CancellationTokenSource> Context { get; } = 
        new AsyncLocal<CancellationTokenSource>();

    public Cancellation()
        : this(CancellationToken.None)
    {
    }

    public Cancellation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        : this(cancellationToken, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
    {
    }

    public Cancellation(int timeout)
        : this(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
    {
    }

    public Cancellation(TimeSpan timeout)
        : this(CancellationToken.None, timeout)
    {
    }

    public Cancellation(CancellationToken cancellationToken, int timeout)
        : this(cancellationToken, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
    {
    }

    public Cancellation(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Parent = Context.Value;
        Context.Value = CancellationTokenSource
            .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

        Context.Value.CancelAfter(timeout);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var cts = Context.Value;
        Context.Value = Parent;
        cts.Dispose();
    }

    CancellationTokenSource Parent { get; }
    public static CancellationToken Token => 
         Context.Value?.Token ?? CancellationToken.None;

    public static void Request() => Context.Value?.Cancel();
    public static bool Requested => Token.IsCancellationRequested;
    public static void ThrowIfRequested() => Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();        
}
```

Comment: This `CancellationTokenSource Parent { get; }` won't work in certain context switching situations that's why the `T` of `AsyncLocal` _must_ be the class itself and link to itself too. I experimented with something similar to your solution and wanted to make it a [generic AsycLocal helper](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.OmniLog/src/LoggerScope.cs#L98) but I had to use the `Action<AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<T>>` ctor overload to make it work when the thread context changed. As this was too tricky I reverted it to use the simpler code.

Comment: This is the issue I experienced: [Restore AsyncLocal.Value on ThreadContextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346693/restore-asynclocal-value-on-threadcontextchanged) - the code was running fine with the debugger but it was failing when run under xunit where it was _loosing_ its `Value` property of `AsyncLocal`.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume you couldn't use `Cancellation` twice at the same time?

Comment: @IEatBagels There is only one `Cancellation` in the context at a given moment, but you could create a nested one with `using(new Cancellation(...) { ... })`. You would need to pass old plain `CancellationToken` explicitly where two or more are required the same time at the same place though - rarely thing to happen.

Comment: @IEatBagels Here you could find a ready to be tried [demo](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/ambientcontext).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it counts as an answer, but the most important missing part was the following ASP.NET Core attribute:

```
public class AmbientContextAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        using (new Op(context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()))
        using (new Cancellation(context.HttpContext.RequestAborted))
            await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: By lack of more answers, I grant you the bounty for the combined question/answer.